Oracle query question related to filtering criterias
Here is my oracle table

Department Table**strong text**
department_id varchar(25) primary key,
employee_id  number,
occupation  varchar(25)
salary      number
as_of_date  date

Data is as follows




department_id
employee_id
occupation
salary




d001
01
Scientist
1000000


d001
02
Engineer
334344


d001
03
Scientist
230000


d001
04
Engineer
330000


d002
04
Scientist
2000000


d002
05
Scientist
1222333


d002
06
Scientist
4000000


d002
07
Scientist
2100000



Please note that in employee table we have department_id d001 which has two occupations Scientist and Engineer. In d002 there is only one occupation Scientist in the 4 records.
Imagine i have thousands of department_id's
i want to fetch only those department_id's which have employees with occupation-> Scientists only and no other occupations. How do i frame such a query
Tried this query but no luck
SELECT department_id
FROM employee
WHERE occupation = 'Scientist'
  AND as_of_date BETWEEN '2024-11-11' AND '2024-11-26'
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT occupation) = 1;


You could simply use MINUS like SELECT department_id FROM employee MINUS SELECT department_id FROM employee WHERE occupation <> 'Scientist' (might be a bit slower because it queries the table twice, depends on indices)

Your WHERE clause removes all non-scientests, this makes it impossible to determine later (in the HAVING clause) whether there were other professions for a department in the table. So move your scientist check from WHERE to HAVING as shown in the answers.

On a side note: Is as_of_date a string column? Otherwise you should not compare with strings ('2024-11-11'), but dates (DATE '2024-11-11').

You can aggregate and use conditional aggregation in the HAVING clause to check the number of non-scientists in each group:
SELECT department_id
FROM   employee
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN occupation <> 'Scientist' THEN 1 END) = 0;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE employee (department_id, employee_id, occupation, salary) AS
SELECT 'd001', '01', 'Scientist', 1000000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd001', '02', 'Engineer',   334344 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd001', '03', 'Scientist',  230000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd001', '04', 'Engineer',   330000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd002', '04', 'Scientist', 2000000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd002', '05', 'Scientist', 1222333 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd002', '06', 'Scientist', 4000000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd002', '07', 'Scientist', 2100000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd003', '08', 'Engineer',   100000 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



DEPARTMENT_ID




d002



fiddle

Few other approaches:
Fiddle
Approach 1
Check where the occupation is only scientist
SELECT department_id
FROM Department
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT occupation) = 1
   AND MAX(occupation) = 'Scientist';

Approach 2
SELECT department_id
FROM Department d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Department d2
    WHERE d.department_id = d2.department_id
    AND d2.occupation != 'Scientist'
)
GROUP BY department_id;

Output


The NOT EXISTS query would query the table twice and in this case I think using MINUS is much simpler.

This might be one option:
Sample data:
SQL> with temp (dept_id, emp_id, occupation) as
  2    (select 'd1', 1, 'Scientist' from dual union all
  3     select 'd1', 2, 'Engineer'  from dual union all
  4     select 'd2', 4, 'Scientist' from dual union all
  5     select 'd2', 5, 'Scientist' from dual
  6    )

Query begins here:
  7  select dept_id
  8  from temp
  9  group by dept_id
 10  having min(occupation) = 'Scientist'
 11     and max(occupation) = 'Scientist';

DEPT_ID
-------
d2

SQL>

